# How select line from array which contains one equal value and one greater, separated by comma?

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I have big text file where lines look like this:

```
9010,6:39:00,6:39:00,U458Z2,29,0,0,""
```

What I need is select line where is fix value "U458Z2" and also where time in third column is equal or greater then DateTime.Now.

I don't know how I can code it. I can't use substring because number in first column has for some rows different length.

I have this for now..

```
 String Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\PIDX\Rady\stops.txt");
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {

            if (line.Contains("U458Z2"))
            {
               //do something

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a library for working with CSV files like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), or just manually split the strings on commas like this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var line in lines) {
    // parts becomes an array of strings
    var parts = line.Split(',');

    // DateTime.Parse will set the date component to today's date when parsing times
    var date = DateTime.Parse(parts[2]);

    var code = parts[3];
    if (code == "U458Z2" && date > now) {
       // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, you posted just before me :P, this is what is the one solution you can use. Thanks